# Can you install two instances of the same desktop environment?

Tags: debian, software-installation, desktop-environment

Probably a stupid question, but I've been using a DE that's still in development (NsCDE) and I've encountered a bug that fundamentally impacts my ability to use it. I cannot seem to fix it after weeks of studying the documentation and troubleshooting.

I was wondering if it were possible to install two instances of it, so as to select a fresh secondary installation from the login screen.

This is of course assuming that the issue wouldn't re-propagate.

Probably not possible. Just thought I'd ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Essentialy it is possible as long as you are using correct Desktop Manager(DM).
I my self am a big fan of Cinnamon Desktop but, way before that, I used gnome2 Desktop, AKA Mate Desktop.

To install Desktop Manager that supports them Desktop Environments, I've chosen `lightdm` and also installed the task files of both of them:

```bash
sudo apt -y install lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings task-cinnamon-desktop task-mate-desktop 
sudo systemctl disable gdm # usually this is what installed on default Debian ISO
sudo systemctl enable lightdm
sudo reboot
```

In case you have some type of different DM, you can check it with:

```
sudo systemctl status display-manager.service
```

The output should hint what you are using:

```
$ sudo systemctl status display-manager.service 
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-06-14 18:36:31 IDT; 1 day 2h ago
       Docs: man:lightdm(1)
```

Hope it helps and don't forget to have some fun :)

Comment: Ah, I worry that there may be an issue installing two instances of the same DE under the same DM. Would that be a problem?

Comment: From my experience, no, it will be somewhat bloated with different tools that do the same thing, because each DE comes with its own set of tools, but besides that it will work like a charm

Comment: Alrighty. Will try this out and report back. Thanks again :)